# Are the music-sheets available in "Jellynote" originals, or User generated transcriptions?

Tags: sheet-music

The title basically is the question. Jellynote offers a big collection of music sheets, tabs, chords and so on for various instruments. However, I didn't anywhere find out wether those are the orignal sheets (either provided, or at least aproved) by the artists, or wether it's just sheets generated and uploaded by the users.

My question especially is targeted towards knowing how accurate the sheets are. The only one who certainly can confirm that the sheets represent the original notes audible is the artist. Everything else may be very plausible guessing, but none the less it remains guessing.

Comment: Check the copyright notices. If there are none, then they are not licensed editions.

Comment: As I didn't sign up there, I don't have access to any of the files.

Comment: Based on what do you assume that if sheet music is licensed, it is somehow more accurate or useful for some purpose? Licensing means that some amount of money probably went to the general direction of a rights owner, which might not be anywhere near the same as "artist" anyway. Unlicensed hobbyist transcriptions can be much more accurate and/or useful, and licensed versions can be very approximate, and/or not representing the actual de-facto canonical version of the song that everyone actually knows. There's a lot of very legal and licensed, but useless sheet music.

Comment: @piiperi I never said anything about licensation. What I meant by "aproved" in question was that the artist had a look on the sheets and decided they represent the original song in the right way.

Comment: In that case I think your question will not be answered. None of those sort of websites publish approval by artists. If you want artist scores you probably need to go to the artist directly.

Comment: And remember sometimes the artist will not even know. The solos I play at most live gigs are broadly improvised on the spot so I wouldn't know what I played. I might have an idea, but no more than that.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp: this "checked and approved" thing is a dream or myth about a perfect world where sheet music is checked by someone, rated Safe for All Musicians by a music correctness authority. ;) Classical music is a bit different, but for pop/rock you will be hard pressed to find sheet music that's exactly right for any particular purpose. If you find sheet music that's exactly the way you want, lucky you. Sheet music is a type of written communication from humans to humans, and it's always a compromise and an approximation based on lots of assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the Jellynote-Team directly via E-mail, and got this answer:

" [...] Until now our content has been only user generated. They're transcriptions made by musicians, not originals made by the artists themselves.
Well, those actually almost never exist: if you think about it, none of the Gallagher brother's reads or writes music... [...]"

This settles the question on where the sheets on Jellynote stem from.

Comment: If you study the world of published pop sheet music, you might encounter quite bad published books that have very approximate melodies, wrong chords, even lyrics. As you get better at transcribing yourself, you're like "why do people pay for that rubbish". There have been efforts to help the situation, for example there was this site called Wikifonia, which attempted to create something like Wikipedia for common "standard" songs, where volunteers could edit lead sheets. It was closed due to licensing issues. Money doesn't care about the accuracy or usefulness of sheet music. So why feed it? ;)

Comment: @piiperi  To be honest (although I agree with the content of your comments) I don't get your comments. I never made a statement about how good I am myself at transcribing (and for multilayered metal-songs, it's not as easy as I'd like it to be), nor did I say anything about licencedness, nor did I say anything about money, nor did I ever indicate any intention to actually sign up at jellynote. I asked this question quite generally, for anybody else who wondered simply where the sheets stem from. Knowing sources is important.

Comment: Hey, thanks and sorry, it's just human communication. If human communication succeeds, it's an accident. The question seemed to reflect a common fallacy or myth about how the world of pop music making works. By saying "as you get better at transribing" I was reflecting my own values, implying that of course everyone makes transcriptions just like everyone tries to become a very good musician, improving their skills every day ... which of course isn't actually true, unfortunately, but to paraphrase some old guy, "you should treat a man as if he already was as good as he can possibly become".